# How can I return immutable data from redux reducer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, immutability

For a learning and test project, I'm trying to return immutable redux data from reducer because safe data for component. this is my reducer code :

```
function itemsReducer(state = [], action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'ITEMS':
            return [...action.data]
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

And this is my loop code :

```
<ul>
    {
        this.props.items.map((item) => (
            <li>{item.name.first} {item.name.last}</li>
        ))
    }
</ul>
```

now every things work right, but after change on props with this method :

```
change() {
    this.props.items[0] = 'empty'
}
```

and after loading again items I have this error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'first' of undefined
```

Apparently the items did not copy with spread syntax in my reducer and all changes override on that. after executing the data load action at all the index #0 is 'empty'

Thank you

Comment: How about using [Immutable JS](https://github.com/immutable-js/immutable-js)?

Comment: How are you dispatching the action, and what is passed in action.data ? how is the data from the store passed to the component ? your problem can come from many places, please add more details

Comment: @Oliver  I've mapped dispatch and action.data comes from my action

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't be mutating the props directly in component, instead dispatch an action that updates the result in reducer

```
change() {
    this.props.updateItem({first: 'empty'}, 0);
}
```

and action creator would be

```
const updateItem = (item, index) => {
   return {type: 'UPDATE_ITEM', item, index}
}
```

and reducer

```
function itemsReducer(state = [], action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'ITEMS':
            return [...action.data]
        case 'UPDATE_ITEM': 
            return [...state.slice(0, action.index), {...state[index], ...action.item}, ...state.slice(index+1)];
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but that change method was a simple way to change props, of course, that method is not suitable to change data. I was testing immutable variable with that method :-)

Comment: @irbgls in order to avoid such issues you can make use of ImmutableJS so that you don't accidently mutate props

Comment: Khatari  I see, but the props aren't immutable ? I've pass the data with immutable syntax, but why that isn't immutable still ?

Comment: using spread syntax to update value doesn't make the props immutable, it just means that while processing ITEMS action you are doing a shallow copy of the state array. Also its a convention that props shouldn't be mutated, but they are mutable like you notice in your case.

Comment: Khatari  yes, that pass data with spread syntax and that's a copy of my api data. but why after clicking on button to receive data my props doesn't refresh and wants to repeat on old data? because that error message ...