# How do I properly return immutable data from a react redux reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

My react redux setup was working well until I needed to trigger a component update based on an update to a redux store variable. From research I feel that my issue is that I am not returning from my reducer in an immutable fashion such that an update is not triggered in the connected component after I dispatch an update to the redux store.

**Action**

```
import {GAMESETUP_IN, GAMESETUP_OUT} from "../api/strings";

export const gameSetupIn = ({gameType, gameRound, gameStocks, gameHistory} = {}) => ({
    type: GAMESETUP_IN,
    gameSetup: {
      gameType,
      gameRound,
      gameStocks,
      gameHistory
    }
});

export const gameSetupOut = () => ({
    type: GAMESETUP_OUT
});
```

**Reducer**

```
// default state
import {GAMESETUP_IN, GAMESETUP_OUT} from "../api/strings";

const gameSetupReducerDefaultState = {
    gameType: "",
    gameRound: "",
    gameStocks: [],
    gameHistory: []
};

// reducer which is a pure function
export default(state = gameSetupReducerDefaultState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GAMESETUP_IN:
            // Return a new array
            return {
                ...state,
                gameType: action.gameSetup.gameType.toString(),
                gameRound: action.gameSetup.gameRound.toString(),
                gameStocks: action.gameSetup.gameStocks,
                gameHistory: action.gameSetup.gameHistory
            };
        case GAMESETUP_OUT:
            return {
                ...state,
                gameType: "",
                gameRound: "",
                gameStocks: [],
                gameHistory: []
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

I feel like there are two very closely related questions.
1) [How can I return immutable data from redux reducer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55511749/how-can-i-return-immutable-data-from-redux-reducer)
2) [Updating Redux state does not trigger componentWillReceiveProps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33322068/updating-redux-state-does-not-trigger-componentwillreceiveprops)

and also the base redux documentation
3) https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers/

I feel like the answer is right in front of me that I need to somehow use return `Object.assign({}, state, { key: newValue });` during the return from redux. I am just looking for some help in modifying my reducer to ensure that it is immutable and thus will trigger a component update after a dispatch. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This all looks non-mutating to me.  Are you mutating any of the variables, e.g. `gameHistory` elsewhere?  Your reducer should be the only function that does that.

You are giving the redux `state` a reference to the history, so if you append anything to that object elsewhere in code it could cause issues.

One solution, as you say, is to use `gameHistory: Object.assign({}, action.gameSetup.gameHistory)` to make a copy, but this will just be a "shallow" copy (if your object contains other objects, they will be copied by reference).  The (disgusting hack, but as far as I know only way for general objects) of making a deep copy is to use `deep_copy_obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(my_obj))`.

The immutable way of doing things is to have your reducer managing things like appending to history, and if you want to edit the history when a button is clicked, make the button dispatch an action.

Comment: Just wanted to say thank you for the vote of confidence that I have it written in a non-mutating manner. I tried removing the state reference but that seemed to have no effect, I tried the shallow copy which actually re-cast the array to an object so that created more problems. I tried the deep copy hack, which actually produced that same behavior as the original code. Bottom line is you are correct and I think my problem must be elsewhere in the app. I think I have some suspect data flow where I copy data from this.props to this.state, basically re-copying redux data versus using it directly.